# How can I validate my request where the data is in a nested structure?

Tags: laravel

My controller receives the following XHR request:

```php
[
  "data" => [
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2",
  ]
]
```

That's why the validation always returns a fail. But I only want to validate the data within data. Is there a request validation function where I only pass the data?

Comment: You can go through your data structure with `data.key1 => 'required'` and thus check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a user mentioned in the comments, you have to iterate each entry by using `data.KEY` format.

If your data is like:

```php
[
    "data" => [
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => "value2",
    ]
]
```

You can validate it like this:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'data' => ['required', 'array'],
        'data.key1' => ['required', 'string', 'in:value1,valueN'],
        'data.key2' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:table,column'],
    ];
}
```

Those rules are just examples, so please, do read [How to validate arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-arrays) as the documentation has a defined section about it.

---

As [Tim Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965631/tim-lewis) correctly mentioned, if all the keys have the same rules, then you can use one single rule and use `data.*`:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'data' => ['required', 'array'],
        'data.*' => ['required', 'string', 'in:value1,valueN'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: If all indices of `data`, like `data.key1`, `data.key2`, etc. are validated the same, then you also don't need to specify each key individually, you can simply do `'data.*' => [...]`, and `key1` through `keyX` will be validated using the same rules 

Answer (score 0):

I assume your controller receives data i.e.

```
public function functionName(Request $request){
   
        $request->validate([
            'key1' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'key2' => 'required'
        ]);
}
```

Comment: The question was asked to know about validating arrays, not single keys.